# Three input files field in one form and save into database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have tried number of threads here is SO to make this but none helping me so far or I miss something here.

So I have one form with three input fields .. I know I can use `multiple` on one field but I need it like this. Here is simple version ( deleted some of the field in order to make source more compact for posting here )

HTML part:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="upload_one">Upload_one: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file[]" id="upload_one">              
            </div>
   </div> 
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="upload_two">Upload_two:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file[]" id="upload_two">
            </div>                      
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="upload_three">Upload_three: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file[]" id="upload_three" multiple>
            </div>                      
   </div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
           <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add New Lesson" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        </div>
   </div>                     
</form>
```

And the PHP part

```
if (isset($_POST["add"])) {
$pdo = Database::connect();
$msg = "";
$permitted = array('application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/bmp');

if (count($_FILES["file"]) > 0) {     
    $folderName = "uploads/";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO upload ( upload_one, upload_two, upload_three, upload_size, upload_type ) 
                    VALUES ( :upload_one, :upload_two, :upload_three, :upload_size, :upload_type )";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

   foreach (array_keys($_FILES) as $file) {
     for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES[$file]["name"]); $i++) {

      if ($_FILES[$file]["name"][$i] <> "") {     
        if ($permitted) {

          $fileSize = $_FILES[$file]["size"][$i];
          $fileType = $_FILES[$file]["type"][$i];
          $fileName = $_FILES[$file]["name"][$i];
          $tmpName  = $_FILES[$file]["tmp_name"][$i];


          $ext = substr(strrchr($fileName, "."), 1);
          $_FILES[$file]["name"][$i] = rand(10000, 990000) . '-' .$fileName;

          $filepath = $folderName . $_FILES[$file]["name"][$i];

          if (!move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filepath)) {
            $emsg .= "Error while uploading file - <strong>" . $_FILES[$file]["name"][$i] . "</strong>. Please try again. <br>";
          } else {
            $smsg .= "The file <strong>" . $_FILES[$file]["name"][$i] . "</strong> is added successfully. <br>";

            try {
              $stmt->bindValue(":upload_one", $_FILES[$file]["name"][$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);  
              $stmt->bindValue(":upload_two", $_FILES[$file]["name"][$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);  
              $stmt->bindValue(":upload_three", $_FILES[$file]["name"][$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);                            
              $stmt->bindValue(":upload_size", $fileSize, PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $stmt->bindValue(":upload_type", $fileType, PDO::PARAM_STR);              


              $stmt->execute();
              $result = $stmt->rowCount();
              if ($result > 0) {
                // file uplaoded successfully.
              } else {
                // failed to insert into database.
              }
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
              $emsg .= "<strong>" . $ex->getMessage() . "</strong>. <br>";
            }
          }
        } else {
          $emsg .= "This file <strong>" . $_FILES[$file]["name"][$i] . "</strong> isn't permitted. <br>";
        }
      }
    }

    $msg .= (strlen($smsg) > 0) ? successMessage($smsg) : "";
    $msg .= (strlen($emsg) > 0) ? errorMessage($emsg) : "";
  } } 
    else {
       echo '';
  }
```

When I hit Add button it is save every input field on one row and the file from that input is three times. For example:

```
`input file_1` have doc1.docx
`input file_2` have doc2.docx
`input file_3` have doc3.docx
```

This will produce this in database:
[image]

You can see how each file is saved 3 times for each input file instead of each file to be just one in his column..

Comment: The way you structures your logic essential means this is happening. Loop File 1 insert row with same name in all 3 fields. File 2 Repeat, File 3 Repeat, End loop

Comment: There are 2 method to approach this, either have all 3 files save on the same row, or each file has its own row. Which one would be more suited to your use case?

Comment: I want to save them on same row. Just each file to be on his column.. Like on the image but `upload_1` to hold file_1, `upload_2` to hold file_2..

Comment: Okay, but what about these 2 rows?

Comment: `$stmt->bindValue(":upload_size", $fileSize, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: `$stmt->bindValue(":upload_type", $fileType, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: You can't populate a fileType with 3 different files, what if they aren't the same type?

Comment: You're right, I must make for each file different column? I will make if I need.. most important is to save all files on one record in database i.e. one row.

Comment: Can i ask why having 1 row is of such importance?

Comment: Because this will be displayed in table on the page. User upload his plan, work, homework etc.. teacher then will check if this user uploaded all this things and will be better if they are on one record because 1 user can upload 100 times this year,.. etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108937/discussion-between-scottevans93-and-select).

Comment: If you only have at most 3 uploads, is the loop really necessary?

Comment: Sometimes in the feature last input field i.e. `input file_3` will go multiple..

Answer (score 2):

Try this for the submit code:

```
{
$pdo = Database::connect();
$msg = "";
$permitted = array('application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/pdf', 'application/msword', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/bmp');

if (count($_FILES["file"]) > 0) 
{     
    $folderName = "uploads/";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO upload ( upload_one, upload_two, upload_three, upload_size, upload_type ) 
                    VALUES ( :upload_0, :upload_1, :upload_2, :upload_size, :upload_type )";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

   foreach (array_keys($_FILES) as $file) 
   {
     for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES[$file]["name"]); $i++) 
     {

      if ($_FILES[$file]["name"][$i] <> "") 
      {     
        if ($permitted) 
        {

          $fileSize = $_FILES[$file]["size"][$i];
          $fileType = $_FILES[$file]["type"][$i];
          $fileName = $_FILES[$file]["name"][$i];
          $tmpName  = $_FILES[$file]["tmp_name"][$i];


          $ext = substr(strrchr($fileName, "."), 1);
          $_FILES[$file]["name"][$i] = rand(10000, 990000) . '-' .$fileName;

          $filepath = $folderName . $_FILES[$file]["name"][$i];

          if (!move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filepath)) {
            $emsg .= "Error while uploading file - <strong>" . $_FILES[$file]["name"][$i] . "</strong>. Please try again. <br>";
          } else {
            $smsg .= "The file <strong>" . $_FILES[$file]["name"][$i] . "</strong> is added successfully. <br>";

            try {
              $stmt->bindValue(":upload_".$i, $_FILES[$file]["name"][$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);  
              $stmt->bindValue(":upload_size", $fileSize, PDO::PARAM_STR);
              $stmt->bindValue(":upload_type", $fileType, PDO::PARAM_STR);              



            } catch (Exception $ex) {
              $emsg .= "<strong>" . $ex->getMessage() . "</strong>. <br>";
            }
          }
        } else {
          $emsg .= "This file <strong>" . $_FILES[$file]["name"][$i] . "</strong> isn't permitted. <br>";
        }
      }
    }

    $msg .= (strlen($smsg) > 0) ? successMessage($smsg) : "";
    $msg .= (strlen($emsg) > 0) ? errorMessage($emsg) : "";
  }
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->rowCount();
      if ($result > 0) {
        // file uplaoded successfully.
      } else {
        // failed to insert into database.
      }

} 
else 
{
   echo '';
}
```

}

Comment: This would work, but it is bad practice as far as logic goes.

Comment: So only this is the difference: `$stmt->bindValue(":upload_".$i, $_FILES[$file]["name"][$i], PDO::PARAM_STR);` ?

Comment: i'm just showing his error , that he made the execution of insert query inside the for loop , which is inserting each files into individual rows.

Comment: the error u made is that you are running the execution code inside the loop which is creating each rows for each uploads. u should run it after the for loop.

Comment: If I add more columns in insert statement it throw error and doesn't save into database and the error is : `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

Comment: I guess because other columns are also `upload_`... `upload_..` and they must match exactly `INTO () VALUES ()`

Comment: yes you need to specify all the other columns aswell., they should be added to the sql.

Comment: Also if some field is empty doesn't save anything in database.. so this mean all fields must be mandatory which is not good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108951/discussion-between-warriorbik-and-select).